# Syntax error near unexpected token '(' after implementing python program

Tags: python

I initally ran RepeatMasker on a Mac, and I am attempting to analyze the file on a Linux OS.

When I try to run my program Unique_Repeat_Code.py:

```
RM_output=open('genomic.fna.out')
contents=RM_output.read'()'
unique_repeats_DNA=open('genomic_unique_repeats.txt','w')
for _ in contents:
    bit_score=column[0]
    percent_div=column[1]
    percent_del=column[2]
    percent_ins=column[3]
    query_seq=column[4]
    position_query_begin=column[5]
    position_query_end=column[6]
    left=column[7]
    sense=column[8]
    matching_repeat=column[9]
    repeat_class=column[10]
    position_in_repeat_begin=column[11]
    position_in_repeat_end=column[12]
    left2=column[13]
    ID=column[14]
    while matching_repeat:
        unique_repeats=set(matching_repeat)
        unique_repeats_DNA.write(unique_repeats)
unique_repeats_DNA.close()
```

in terminal I get the following error:

```
./Unique_Code.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token '('
./Unique_Code.py: line 6: 'RM_output=open('genomic.fna.out')'
```

Any help in fixing this problem would be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is `contents=RM_output.read'()'` supposed to do?  I think you have some misplaced quotes there.

Comment: Also, wouldn't `while matching_repeat:` be an infinite loop?  The value of `matching_repeat` would never change inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Also also, where does `column` come from?

Comment: Also also also, `for _ in contents:` will not loop over every line in your file, it will loop over every *character*.  What *exactly* does `genomic.fna.out` contain and what are you trying to do?

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes, there were misplaced quotes. I'm a novice programmer, and I'm still learning a few things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running your script as a bash script when you use the "./" syntax. You need to use the python interpreter to run your script:

```
python Unique_Code.py
```